# turn two coulmns into key value pairs in python

Tags: python, class, csv

I would like to know if there is a nice way to take a two column tab delimited text file and use python to create an instantiation of a class that reads the first column as the keys and the second column as the associated values.

I want to have the class instantiate itself given one of these text files if possible! Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's possible. Easy even. However, please don't just dump a bunch of requirements with no evidence of your own effort to fulfill them.

Comment: Happy to upload what I have, but it doesn't work so I don't know how much help that will be, especially if the solution is easy!

Comment: This solved it:<br/>dataframe = pd.read_csv(filenames[0], sep = ':')<br/>

for filename in filenames[1:]:<br/>
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ':')<br/>
    dataframe = pd.merge(dataframe, df, how = 'outer', on = '*column name to be merged on*')

Answer (score 1):

Open the file and iterate line by line. Split each line on the tab using regex, and then add them to your dictionary. Wrap the code in a class if you want.

```
import re

myvars = {}
with open("<FILENAME>.txt") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        values = re.split(r'\t+', line)
        myvars[values[0]] = values[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [dict()](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.dict) builtin does exactly what you want

```
dict(line.split() for line in open('foo.txt'))
```

Comment: You might want to do `line.split()[:2]` or even `line.split('\t', 1)`. On the other hand, your way of throwing an error if a line has more than two elements is also very nice.

Comment: Also, better stick this in a with block for the file.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes I know, but since file is not used outside of expression it should be garbage collected once the expression is evaluated.
Anyway garbage collection is up to implementation, so you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the file you are trying to parse is called `foo.txt` and is in the same directory you are running the following code:

```
data = dict()

with open("foo.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        key, value = line.split()
        data[key] = value
```

If the content of the file `foo.txt` is:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

after running the code above `data` should be

```
{ "a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3" }
```